# real time Texas Holdem

Tags: real-time, game-engine, poker, partial-page-refresh

I'm designing a multiplayer poker site and require a way to display changes that occur during game play on all users screens that are active at the table including Ai decisions?

I'm coding using the MVC Structure, and currently making use of C#, javascript and html5

I've attempted using meta tags

and javascript intervals, but unfortunately all it does is continuously refreshes the entire screen, even when partial views are used

I'm looking for something to maintain real time gameplay

Comment: Answering this question properly would require answers that are too long for this format. However, look up [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest You look into JavaScript JSON or Ajax controls.
Meta tags won't help as they as designed to refresh the entire page and you often see the lag of loading the page between IE9 and Google Chrome. That would definitely adversely affect your multi-player environment.
Stick with the partial view, because that is the way to go, but in your view have a Ajax function, datatype:json , type:post, and use the success of the function to do whatever process is required.